# TypeScript: return only first value of an ObjectSet

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I am pretty new to TypeScript and especially to the custom Palantir implementation for Object(Sets). What I am trying to archive: I'd like to filter an ObjectSet down to some specific values. Then I'd like to return the first of these values. In fact I'd just like to return a single line.
What I've done so far:

```
    @Function()
    public nextUnprocessedValueString(inputObject: ObjectSet<CombinedSentencesForTagging>): ObjectSet<CombinedSentencesForTagging>{
        const result = Objects.search().combinedSentencesForTagging().filter(f => f.customerFeedback.exactMatch('i like it very much.'))
        return result
```

The result looks like this:
[image: result]

What I would need is only the first line (or a random line).

Thanks!

Comment: I can't easily find any documentation for PF, but: I assume `result` in that function is an array of those filtered values (like the 3 in the screenshot), correct? Just take the first index of that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
@Function()
public nextUnprocessedValueString(inputObject: ObjectSet<CombinedSentencesForTagging>): CombinedSentencesForTagging {
    const result = 
           inputObject.filter(f => f.customerFeedback.exactMatch('i like it very much.'))
                      .orderBy(f => f.customerFeedback.asc())
                      .take(1);
    
    return result[0];
}
```

Here are the changes I made to the original function:

1. Changed the return type to a single `CombinedSentencesForTagging` object.
2. Modified the `filter` line to run on the `inputObject` specified in the function's parameters
3. Used the `orderBy` and `take` filter clauses to pick just one of the filtered results.